# Column store index for on premise Kimball Data Warehouses

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, data-warehouse, columnstore

Are column store tables now the vendor default method for Kimball Data Warehouse tables with Dim and Facts for On Premise?

I know in the cloud, Microsoft automatically recommends Azure Data warehouses use column store. How about on premise? Is this the vendor solution, or should I conduct row based testing?

We have SQL 2016, 50 cores, 200GB of RAM.
Database consumes 500GB each year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of SQL 2016 Clustered Columnstore Indexes should be your default choice for Fact tables in a Kimball-style dimensional model, possibly with the addition of a non-clustered primary key to prevent duplicate rows.  See [Columnstore indexes - Design guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-design-guidance?view=sql-server-2017)

Dimension tables should typically use row-based Clustered Indexes, with additional non-clustered indexes for business keys.